# Mongoose duplicate queries

Tags: mongoose

All mongoose queries I see twice at my IDE. Update queries creates two records on a collection, with the same create time. If I try console.log any text before queries executes by schema.query method, the text outputs once. Im really puzzled what it can be consists of..[image: IDE LOG]

So, I call mongoose schema method throught arrow function with braces:

```
const findOneAndUpdate = (schema, filter, update, options) => {
        schema.findOneAndUpdate(filter, update, options, (err, list) =>{ if (err) {console.log(err)} else list} )
}
```

- In this case method calls one times.

  But if I call method without braces:

  const findOneAndUpdate = (schema, filter, update, options) => schema.findOneAndUpdate(filter, update, options, (err, list) =>{ if (err) {console.log(err)} else list} )
- It calls two times

Comment: Data is not enough to ans this question. Please provide more details.

Comment: Just update question data